# Symfony2 Making functions for pricing confusion

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am at the part where I need to dynamically change the pricings in the cart, based on the quantity of same products I want to buy. Im stuck at this part because I think I made the whole shopping cart logic kinda stupid and now its really hard to get the pricings. OR maybe I am wrong?

So the whole idea behind the shopping cart is:

I have a products entity with all of the products information and functions in it, such as getPrice, getDiscount and etc.. When I add a product to the cart, I create a new array $cart, but I only save the productsId there, and the productsId has a value(the products quantity) and thats it. This is what I mean:

```
 if($session->has('cart') && count($session->get('cart')) > 0 ) {

             $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                foreach( $cart as $id => $quantity ) {
                          $productIds[] = $id;      
                } 
            if( isset( $productIds ) )
                {
                    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                    $product = $em->getRepository('MpShopBundle:Product')->findById( $productIds );
                } else {
                    return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig', array(
                        'empty' => true,
                    ));
                }

               return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig',     array(
            'product' => $product,
                    ));
                } else {
                    return $this->render('MpShopBundle:Frontend:product_summary.html.twig',     array(
                        'empty' => true,
                    ));
                }
            }
```

Now when I want to display the items in the cart based on productsId I simply do this:

```
{% if product is defined %}

         {% if cart is defined %}

              {% for info in product %}

                <tr>

                  <td> <img width="60" src="{{ asset('bundles/mpFrontend/assets/products/6.jpg') }}" alt=""/></td>

                  <td>{{ info.model }}</td>
                  <td>

                  {% for key, item in cart %}

                {% if key == info.id %}

                    <div class="input-append">

                    <input class="span1" style="max-width:34px" placeholder="{{ key }}" value="{{ item }}" id="appendedInputButtons" size="16" type="text" data-id="{{ key }}"/>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove btn"><i class="icon-minus"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add btn"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a>

                    {% endif %}

                    {% endfor %}

                    {% for key in cart|keys %}

                    {% if key == info.id %}

                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><a href="{{ path('cart_remove', {'id': key}) }}"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></button>

                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>

                  </td>

                  <td>{{ info.price }}</td>
                  <td>{{ info.discount }}</td>
                  <td>{{ info.value }}</td>


                  <td>{{ info.getFinal|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>


                </tr>


 {% endfor %}


                <tr>
                  <td colspan="6" align="right">Total Price:    </td>
                  <td> ${{getTotalPrice(product)|number_format(2, '.', ',')}}</td>
                </tr>

                 <tr>
                  <td colspan="6" align="right">Total Discount: </td>
                  <td> ${{getTotalDiscount(product)|number_format(2, '.', ',')}}</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td colspan="6" align="right">Total Tax:  </td>
                  <td> ${{getTotalTax(product)|number_format(2, '.', ',')}}</td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td colspan="6" align="right"><strong>TOTAL</strong>  </td>
                  <td class="label label-important"> <strong> ${{getTotalCart(product)|number_format(2, '.', ',')}} </strong></td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>

{% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

As you can see there are a lot of for's which kinda annoys me too. But the problem as when I want to display the prices:

I can display a single price easy, using `info.price` and so on.. But this only displays the price when there is 1 of the same type product. I get get the full price of all products too with an twig extension like this:

```
public function getTotalCart($items)
    {
    $total = 0;
    foreach($items as $item){

        $total += $item->getFinal();
    }
    return $total;
    }
```

But like I said, it only works when the products quantity is 1.
So my question is: How can I create a function, that gets the price from the product entity and the quantity from $cart array and then sums it all up? Is that even possible? Or maybe there is a way to save all of the products information in $cart and then access it? I dont know..

I know I can make it like `{{ info.price * item }}` but I want the price to be saved somewhere not just display it.

This is what I came up with until now:

```
public function getTotalCart($items, $cart)
    {
    $qtyTotal = 0;
    foreach($cart as $id=>$quantity) {      
        $qtyTotal += $quantity * getItemPrice($id, $items);
    }
    return $qtyTotal;
    }

    public function getItemPrice($id, $items){

        return $this->getFinal();
    }
```

I get the error: `Attempted to call function "getItemPrice" from namespace "Mp\ShopBundle\twig".` I am probably not writing this function right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have each price for a product depending on its quantity, the $total variable is not useful here. You should probably do something like that :

```
foreach($cart as $id=>$quantity) {      
        $qtyTotal += $quantity * getItemPrice($id, $items);
    }
```

Where getItemPrice is a function returning the price of the item with `$id`.

Comment: If you return $this->getFinal() in your function you'll always return the same price. Maybe something like that would do the trick, even though I'm not sure it's the best way for performance :

Comment: public function getItemPrice($id, $items){

        foreach ($items as $item){
          if ($item->getId() == $id) return $item->getFinal();
        }
}

Comment: Hey, I am still getting this error: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException: "Attempted to call function "getItemPrice" from namespace "Mp\ShopBundle\twig"." at C:\wamp\www\Digidis\tree\src\Mp\ShopBundle\Twig\AppExtension.php line 40

Comment: Do you functions belong to an object ? If so, try to call it with $this->getItemPrice. Otherwise, maybe put the getItemPrice declaration before the other function. I don't see much more right now as I don't know in what context are the functions written